# js2coffee throws cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have js2coffee installed globally and I tried

```
    js2coffee app.js > app.coffee
```

And I got the following error

```
    module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'nopt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/js2coffee/out/lib/command.js:16:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/js2coffee/out/lib/command.js:273:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/js2coffee/out/bin/js2coffee:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the nopt module is a `devDependency` of js2coffee and isn't installed during production.

To fix this, navigate to js2coffee's module folder and run `npm install`. That will also install development dependencies, although I'm not sure why js2coffee needs them the way you're using it.

So if you're using running a Linux machine, use these commands:

```
cd /usr/lib/node_modules/js2coffee
npm install
```

Comment: might help others if you tell em how you figured out the devDependency part

Comment: I never thought to do it, but if you look in /usr/lib/node_modules/js2coffee/package.json, you can see nopt under devDependencies.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake, version 0.2.2 had a bug. js2coffee 0.2.3 fixed this issue: https://github.com/js2coffee/js2coffee/blob/master/HISTORY.md#v023---october-19-2013

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you installed the package globally using -g option.Try installing the package like

```
npm install package
```

in the project directory

Comment: did u install npm install package in project directory?

Comment: @mao3 try npm ls and see if your package is dere??

Comment: can u post your package.json